# Is there a way I can use a method to add <string,string> to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code to track errors in my application:

```
Crashes.TrackError(ex,
   new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"RunQuery", "Exception"},
        {"sql", s },
        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
        {"Exception", ex.ToString()}
   });
```

Now I find that parameter length is limited to 125 characters. Is there a way that instead of adding: `{"sql", s }` I could substitute in something that would break that down into multiple  with the max length of 125?

I need something the equivalent of:

```
Crashes.TrackError(ex,
   new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"RunQuery", "Exception"},
        {"sql", s1 },
        {"sql", s2 },
        {"sql", s3 },
        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
        {"Exception", ex.ToString()}
   });
```

Where this is generated with a method call:

```
        {"sql", s1 },
        {"sql", s2 },
        {"sql", s3 },
```

Like:

```
Crashes.TrackError(ex,
   new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"RunQuery", "Exception"},
        myMethod("sql", s),
        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
        {"Exception", ex.ToString()}
   });
```

Comment: If 'parameter length is limited to 125 characters' where will you be getting info from after the 125th character? If there are only 125 characters, splitting it into multiple parts with max length 125 will not be hard to do 

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and I do have two Articles I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | You should first and foremost log Exception.ToString(). And in that case, all you need is a `List<String>`. Personally I would never try to store Exceptions in memory. I would try to write them back to a file ASAP. Keeping them in memory is just asking to loose them.

Comment: If you are using `Dictionary`, there is no possibility to have the same key ('sql' in your code) many times (with values `s1`, `s2` etc.).

Comment: @Alan2, maybe you can update your question and add the Xamarin tag and change the title to something like 'How to bypass Crashes.TrackError limitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

But you can do the following:

```
Crashes.TrackError(ex, DictionaryOfStringFromErrorInfo( s, DeviceInfo, ex ) );
```

and then you can have this:

```
IDictionary<string,string> DictionaryOfStringFromErrorInfo( string s,
    DeviceInfo deviceInfo, Exception ex )
{
    Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add( "RunQuery", "Exception" );
    List<string> parts = s.ConvertToChunkList(125);
    dictionary.Add( "Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model );
    dictionary.Add( "Exception", ex.ToString() );
    for( int i = 0;  i < parts.Count;  i++ )
        dictionary.Add( "Sql" + i, parts[i] );
    return dictionary;
}
```

You can even pass `Crashes` to the function, so that it can also do the `Crashes.TrackError()` call.

That having been said, your `Crashes.TrackError()` accepts `ex`, and you are also passing `ex.ToString()`, so that looks redundant.

But the the most important thing is that the limitation of 125 characters is retarded, and nowadays there is never any real technological reason for such limitations.

If it is technically feasible to remove this limitation, do not rest until you have removed it, no matter what the cost is.

If you are using some product that places this limitation, throw away that product, use another one.

If some engineer in your organization put this limitation in place "just because," make it look like they had an accident.

Comment: Apparently there is also a limit (20) in the number of element in the dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/errors/